# Variable being changed inside for loop for no reason

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

```
for(int g = 0; g <= width; g++)
{
    std::cout << width << "\n";
    std::cout << g << "\n";
    for(int h = 0; h <= height; h++)
    {
        int rx = g;
        int ry = h;
        if(h == 0 || img.GetPixel(rx, ry - 1) == sf::Color::Black)
        {
            cells[g/2][h/2].up = true;
        }
        if(g == 0 || img.GetPixel(rx - 1, ry) == sf::Color::Black)
        {
            cells[g/2][h/2].left = true;
        }
    }
}
```

So I've go this code here. Width is set to 197, and it's working great, filling out the whole array. However, when g hits 196 width just randomly changes to 453. I have no idea what is going on, can anyone help me?

The purpose of this program is to loop through an array and assign walls to cells if needed be (it's a maze).

I've confirmed that width is changing, not something else. I can't see why anything would change that though, there are no other threads running and img is from SFML so nothing should happen.

Pastebin of the surrounding, relevant code: http://pastebin.com/Q7jyZYrR
Requires SFML, if you comment out the parts that use it the crash doesn't happen.

Comment: So you say that `img.GetWidth()` returns 197 each time around the loop until suddenly it changes to 453. Hard for us to tell you why that happens with out knowing what's in `img.GetWidth()`. Look inside the implementation of `img.GetWidth()` to work out the answer.

Comment: From what I see, the only way `width` can change if some other thread is doing something with the `img` object............

Comment: Why do you assign width within every iteration of the loop? Would it not be sufficient to query width once above the loop?

Comment: Hm. Just commented out the image lines to see if that had anything to do with problem and it stopped. The loop is supposed to loop through the image (a maze) and add walls where needed.

Comment: You need to add more context to the question, else it's really hard to give an answer. (hence the down voyes). Add more detail to you question, not just a blob of code and you'll get answers and upvotes.

Comment: @Thilo That was a frantic measure by me to stop width from changing.

Comment: If you use Linux, compile with `g++ -Wall -g` and use `gdb` to debug, then its `watch` command for `width`

Comment: Did you assign a value to `width` before entering the loop?  If not, `g <= width` is accessing an uninitialized variable, with unpredictable results.  (And you don't need to reassign it inside the loop, unless it's going to be changing, but that's mostly an efficiency issue.)  Assuming `width` is ok, your outer loop iterates `width+1` times, which seems very odd; `for (int g = 0; g < width; g++)` would be more idiomatic.  How is `cells` declared?  Is it possible that you're assigning elements outside the bounds of `cells`?

Comment: Can you post a *small* and *complete* version of the program that exhibits the problem, so we don't have to ask all these questions?

Comment: Cells is declared with the half width and height of the picture, which I take into account by /2ing the values for going into cells.

Comment: It would not be possible for an out of bounds access to happen, except in this case width is mysteriously being changed.

Comment: Fixed the issue with it jumping by commenting the rx/ry lines (No idea how that fixed anything) but now it's segaulting on g == 0 (I've isolated it's caused by that. If I don't get it fixed in the next 20 minutes I'm moving on and trying a different implementation of doing this.

Comment: Apparently that's not the problem. I'm just going to continue on my own now.

Comment: It's probably segfaulting on `g == 0` because you are subtracting 1 from the indices in the `GetPixel()` calls and you are passing `-1`. Is `-1` a valid parameter value for that function?

Answer (score 2):

I would guess you are overflowing the cells[][] array if height is an even number due to the loops using `h <= height` as an end condition. For example, consider `height=2` which makes `cells[][1]` and you overflow when `h=2` on `cells[][h/2]` => `cells[][1]`. This also would occur if width is even.

Either change the end condition on the two loops to `<` or increase the size of the `cells` array by one in each dimension.

Answer (score 0):

`width`  is a condition in the `for` loop, but you are changing `width`'s value 
every loop with 
`width = img.GetWidth();`

```
for(int g = 0; g <= width; g++) 
{ 
    width = img.GetWidth();
```

Put it outside before the `for` loop..

```
width = img.GetWidth(); 
for(int g = 0; g <= width; g++) 
{
```

Comment: The witdh inside the loop was simply a frantic measure by me to stop that from changing at the end, which didn't work. That line is also outside the loop.

Comment: Suggestion: Rather than re-assigning it inside the loop (which will at best hide any underlying problem), add (temporary) code to *check* that it has the expected value, and die with an clear error message if it's changed.